# p-dropdown not being tabbable after primeng upgrade to latest version

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-dropdowns

After upgrading primeng in my application, p-dropdown is now not tabbable

```
<p-dropdown id="fieldID" [options]="fieldOptions"
                                    formControlName="field" optionLabel="name"
                                        optionValue="id"></p-dropdown>
```

This is what it looked like before upgrade and I was able to tab into the field, and keep tabbing through other fields. But after the upgrade, when I tab into the field, it is unable to tab away and into other fields. I tried to add [tabindex]="0" to the element but it has no effect on the tabbing issue. Why is this and how else can I fix this?
I am noticing that it is tabbable when the options field is not present, however this is needed to populate the dropdown

Comment: Ran into this too and it seems that there is already an open [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13774) on GitHub. So keep an eye on the progress